# Should you have different protos for write and list, or reuse?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net, protobuf-java

When designing CRUD protos, the write service will have to write to multiple relational tables, so you would design the protos in a way that match the table schema and will have some kind of nested structure as well. This is not the same for the list operation as we abstract the data in a flat structure in a NOSQL structure. What is the recommendation on this case? Do I reuse the nested protos and transform the NOSQL response to unify the proto structure between the read and write? Or should I write a custom proto that is flat for the list service?

Is this actually a case by case and a design decision? Or is there some enforced opinion somewhere that I have to follow?

Answer (score 0):

There are many schools of thought on API design. Given that you're talking about Google products (protobuf and gRPC), you may find Google's API Design Guide helpful. https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/.